# After some sessions, Windows 10 Pro RDC displays a black screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop

We are using 2 Windows 10 Pro computers, and an issue arises after using several Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) sessions.

Specifically, during some RDP sessions, the screen turns black, and after a few seconds, the RDP connection gets disconnected.

When I check the Event Viewer, I find an error message stating, "The Windows logon process has unexpectedly terminated" with Event ID 4005.

After a few RDP sessions, the problem occurred. The RDP settings have been enabled, and the RDP services function correctly on the Windows 10 Pro computer.

I tried Windows Resource Protection, but it found no corrupted files.

After restarting the PC, the problem is resolved, but the same problem occurs again after a while.

Please let me know if any specific troubleshooting steps exist to resolve the issue.

Comment: On each affected computer run DISM / SFC   ... See if any change.   (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have followed those steps, but the issue reoccurs after some time.